# MobX don't update react DOM in fetch promise callback

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

I am trying to update a react dom by changing an observable mobx variable inside a fetch callback in a react typescript app but mobx don't show any reaction on variable change. 
I define my variable like this:

```
@observable  data:any = []
```

and in my constructor i change data value:

```
 constructor(){
        this.data.push(
            {
                count:0,
                dateTime:'2017'
            })
        this.getData();
    }
```

its work fine and update dom properly as expected.
in `getData()` method i write a fetch  to retrive data from server :

```
@action getData(){
   this.data.push(
     {
      count:1,
      dateTime:'2018'
     })
    fetch(request).then(response=>response.json())
    .then(action((data:Array<Object>)=>{
        this.data.push(data)
        console.log(data)
    }));
}
```

so my view now shows 2 value the 2017 and 2018 object data but the 2019 data that I get from the server is not showing. the log shows the correct values and variable filled in a right way but mobx don't update view after I set any variable in fetch function callback and I don't know why?
p.s: I do the same in ECMA and there was no problem but in typescript mobx act differently

Comment: Your component is an observer?

Comment: I'm not sure if that answers the question. What he meant was, does your component have an `@observer` decorator on it?

Comment: I think you're going to need to provide an [mcve] for this.

Comment: The problem is not mobx. Mobx is not responsible for updating the view. So it's either react, or mobx-react. You said you have used @observer so what might be the problem is on the React side. Maybe you didn't set the "key" value properly on the component while mapping over the values. That can cause react to render wrongly. Without more code, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Try instead of pushing into the observable try copying the array, adding value on the copy and assigning it back to the observable
`const data = [...this.data];`
`data.push(data);`
`this.data = data;`
`

Answer (score 1):

Check my approach:

```
import { action, observable, runInAction } from 'mobx'

class DataStore {
  @observable data = null
  @observable error = false
  @observable fetchInterval = null
  @observable loading = false

  //*Make request to API
  @action.bound
  fetchInitData() {
    const response = fetch('https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker')
    return response
  }

  //*Parse data from API
  @action.bound
  jsonData(data) {
    const res = data.json()
    return res
  }

  //*Get objects key and push it to every object
  @action.bound
  mapObjects(obj) {
    const res = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
      let newData = obj[key]
      newData.key = key
      return newData
    })
    return res
  }

  //*Main bound function that wrap all fetch flow function
  @action.bound
  async fetchData() {
    try {
      runInAction(() => {
        this.error = false
        this.loading = true
      })
      const response = await this.fetchInitData()
      const json = await this.jsonData(response)
      const map = await this.mapObjects(json)
      const run = await runInAction(() => {
        this.loading = false
        this.data = map
      })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      runInAction(() => {
        this.loading = false
        this.error = err
      })
    }
  }

  //*Call reset of MobX state
  @action.bound
  resetState() {
    runInAction(() => {
      this.data = null
      this.fetchInterval = null
      this.error = false
      this.loading = true
    })
  }

  //*Call main fetch function with repeat every 5 seconds
  //*when the component is mounting
  @action.bound
  initInterval() {
    if (!this.fetchInterval) {
      this.fetchData()
      this.fetchInterval = setInterval(() => this.fetchData(), 5000)
    }
  }

  //*Call reset time interval & state
  //*when the component is unmounting
  @action.bound
  resetInterval() {
    if (this.fetchInterval) {
      clearTimeout(this.fetchInterval)
      this.resetState()
    }
  }
}

const store = new DataStore()
export default store
```

Answer (score 0):

as @mweststrate mentioned in the comments, it was an observer problem  and when I add `@observer` on top of my react class the problem get fixed

Comment: So when you mentioned in the question ”my component has @observer” it actually didn't have it?

Comment: yes but it's about @action.bound too. I didn't try both of them together ty for mentioning